# Passing an array created from fscanf into a new function

Tags: c, scanf

I have successfully fscanf a text file and saved in to an array E2N1. I am trying to pass this into a function as a pointer but it is not working. Whenever I try to call E2N1[0][0], it says that E2N is neither an array or a pointer. I've been looking all over for a solution on this. 
(Sorry E2N was meant to be E2N1)
I use fscanf as:

```
int E2N1[noz.rowE2N][Q.N];

FILE* f = fopen("E2N.txt", "r");
for(i=0; i<noz.rowE2N; i++){
    for (j=0; j<Q.N; j++){
        fscanf(f,"%d",&E2N1[i][j]);

    }
    fscanf(f,"\n");

}
fclose(f);
```

and again I can't pass E2N1 into function.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

The function is:

```
double *dudtF = stiffness(&U, &massM, &noz, &newV, &E2N1, &I2E, &B2E, &PP, &QQ);
```

and I write the function header as:

```
double *stiffness(double *U, double *massM, MESH *meshN, double *V1, int *E2N1, int *I2E, int *B2E, ordApprox *pp, ordApprox *qq)
```

V1, I2E, B2E are three arrays and I'm trying to do the same with them as I am trying to do with E2N1.

Comment: Can you show how you are passing this to the function? Arrays are like addresses so you have to pass a pointer to the array to your function.

Comment: *and again I can't pass E2N1 into function.* - what function?

Comment: @ykmizu: can you provide related code also?

Comment: From the details provided, I believe you have saved into array named: E2N, but you are trying to access E2N1. Maybe thats the problem.

Comment: Sorry E2N was meant to be E2N1.

Comment: @ykmizu: provide the code where you have declared E2N1.

Comment: How did you define and allocate E2N1?

Comment: Provided. and E2N1 is initialized as int E2N1[noz.rowE2N][Q.N];

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing about arrays is that they actually act as pointers.

if you have array `char a[3]` the variable is equivalent to `char* p` the same way if you have array `char b[3][4]` the variable `b` is equivalent to `char** q`. In other words, you should consider changing the handling in the method to take reference to reference (and possibly once more to reference) to integer.

Try google... here are some results I've got.

http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/illustrate-2d-array-int-pointers-929.aspx

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ab/15-123S09/lectures/Lecture%2006%20-%20%20Pointer%20to%20a%20pointer.pdf

Comment: Do *not* declare the E2N1 parameter as a pointer-to-pointer. It is a linear sequence 2D array on the caller side, it is NOT a pointer array, which is something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass as `&E2N1`, just pass as `E2N1` no `&` as array name itself translates to pointer.

```
double *dudtF = stiffness(&U, &massM, &noz, &newV, E2N1, &I2E, &B2E, &PP, &QQ);
```

Also, you need to take it as `int **` as its 2-dimensional array.

```
double *stiffness(double *U, double *massM, MESH *meshN, double *V1, int **E2N1, int *I2E, int *B2E, ordApprox *pp, ordApprox *qq)
```

Comment: As stated in another answer. E2N1 on the caller side is *not* a pointer array. it is a fully sequential 2D array in row major order. A pointer-to-pointer is not the silver bullet you think it is in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example how to transfer matrix from one function to another ...

```
void foo (int **a_matrix)
{
int value = a_matrix[9][8];
a_matrix[9][8] = 15;
}

void main ()
{
#define ROWS 10
#define COLUMNS 10

int **matrix = 0;
matrix = new int *[ROWS] ;
for( int i = 0 ; i < ROWS ; i++ )
matrix[i] = new int[COLUMNS];

matrix[9][8] = 5;

int z = matrix[9][8] ;

foo (matrix);

z = matrix[9][8] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a multi-dimensional array passed to a function by point referencing as in the following:

```
int iVals[10][10];
foo(iVals);

void foo(int** pvals)
{
    // accessing the array as follows will cause an access violation
    cout << pvals[0][1]; // access violation or unpredictable results
}
```

You will need to specify the second dimension to the array in the function prototype
for example:

```
foo(int ivals[][10])
{
    cout << ivals[0][1];  // works fine
}
```

If do not know the dimensions, then I would suggest you follow the principles outlined here:

```
void foo(int *p, int r, int c)
{
    for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", p[i*c+j]);
        }
    }
}

int c[6][6];

// pointer to the first element
foo(&c[0][0], 6, 6);

// cast
foo((int*)c, 6, 6);

// dereferencing
foo(c[0], 6, 6);

// dereferencing
foo(*c, 6, 6);
```

I hope this helps.

Alternatively you could use SAFEARRAY - see:
http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/passing-multi-dimensional-managed-array-to-c-part-2/